# cifs mounted devices not shown in lsblk

Tags: cifs

Why are my cifs mounted devices are not shown in lsblk list?

The mount and also auto mount of my cifs (external SSD) at startup works great with this `/etc/fstab` config

```
//__MY_IP__/FRITZ.NAS/ /home/openhabian/fritzNAS cifs credentials=/home/openhabian/.smbcredentials,vers=3.0,noserverino,uid=1000,gid=1000,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.requires=network-online.target 0 0
```

I can read and write to the SSD!

But why is this storage not shown in lsblk?

```
openhabian@openhabian:/ $ sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
NAME        FSTYPE  SIZE MOUNTPOINT      LABEL
mmcblk0            29.1G                 
├─mmcblk0p1 vfat    256M /boot           boot
└─mmcblk0p2 ext4   28.9G /               rootfs
zram0                 1G [SWAP]          
zram1               750M /opt/zram/zram1 
zram2                 1G /opt/zram/zram2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `man lsblk`:

```
DESCRIPTION
   lsblk lists information about all available or the specified block
   devices. The lsblk command reads the sysfs filesystem and udev db to
   gather information. If the udev db is not available or lsblk is
   compiled without udev support, then it tries to read LABELs, UUIDs and
   filesystem types from the block device. In this case root permissions
   are necessary.
```

So the answer is that cifs mounted devices are not block-devices, but virtual. lsblk will only list disks that are physical available in the computer.